# Deleting a page (?)

Tags: web-part, app

I found a bookmark in my browser that was pointing to a page on my SharePoint 2013 environment (with Project Server 2013) like this http//dev/PWA/**TheApp**
I want to delete this site, but couldn't find it on the Site contents of http//dev/PWA/. So I thought "Maybe it's an App?..." (because Apps are not supposed to appear on the Site Contents). So I went to Central Administration App Catalogue, but as it turns out, the site http//dev/, doesn't even have an App Catalogue...
So I thought "Maybe it's a Web part?..." so I went to the Site Settings -> Solutions, but there are no web parts there.

After opening SharePoint Designer and looking into "All files" I saw a folder name **TheApp** with a aspc file inside it, but the deete button is greyed out and if I click the aspx file I get the warning below:

[image: Not permitted]

But looking at SharePoint Designer permissions for the http//dev/ site, this is what's configured:
[image: Designer permissions]

So... It's not an App, it's not a Web part, and I can't delete it with SP Designer... What is it and how can I delete it?

NB: sorry for any error in understanding the problem but I'm still learning my way around this technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to delete the site using SharePoint Manager (https://spm.codeplex.com/).

As an additional information, I tried removing the DisableWebDesignFeatures property (as explained [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ccdc26d8-6f34-478f-83bb-ab2bf3de59e3/deleting-a-page-?forum=sharepointadmin#ccdc26d8-6f34-478f-83bb-ab2bf3de59e3)) however that didn't worked.